# React pass cache and get/set function in context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I cant seem to get the below code to work. Trying to have some simple "cache" in react which I want to pass down from the App component using context.
State is present in App as follows:

```
  const [cacheData, setCacheData] = useState({});
  const getCache = (key) => {
    console.log('Getting value from cache with key ' + key, cacheData);
    return cacheData[key];
  }
  const setCache = (key, data) => {
    try{
      console.log(cacheData);

      console.log('Setting value to cache with key ' + key, data);
      let dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cacheData));
      dataCopy[key] = data;
      console.log(dataCopy, cacheData);
      setCacheData(dataCopy); 
      console.log('jaja');
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Then it is passed down to context like this:

```
<CacheContext.Provider value={{data: cacheData, get: getCache, set: setCache}}>
```

In a child component I use cache.get and cache.set, all have correct console.logs, but the cache is always undefined. Cachedata is always `{}`. My guess is that the setCache function isnt doing anything.

Thanks in advance guys. Also, if you think I am reinventing the wheel please point me to some help :) couldnt find any package which did this for me.

Snippet: (copied from answer, this one works. Will add the faulty code)

```js
const {useState, useContext, createContext} = React

const fn = () => undefined
const CacheContext = createContext({data: {}, get: fn, set: fn})

const App = () => {
  const [cacheData, setCacheData] = useState({});
  const getCache = (key) => {
    console.log('Getting value from cache with key ' + key, cacheData);
    return cacheData[key];
  }
  const setCache = (key, data) => {
    try{
      console.log(cacheData);

      console.log('Setting value to cache with key ' + key, data);
      let dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cacheData));
      dataCopy[key] = data;
      console.log(dataCopy, cacheData);
      setCacheData(dataCopy); 
      console.log('jaja');
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <CacheContext.Provider value={{data: cacheData, get: getCache, set: setCache}}>
      <Main />
    </CacheContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useCache = () => useContext(CacheContext)

const Main = () => {
  const cache = useCache()
  const [key, setKey] = useState('key')
  const [value, setValue] = useState('value')
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={key} onChange={(e) => setKey(e.target.value)} /> :
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => cache.set(key, value)}>Set</button>
      <div>Existing keys: [{Object.keys(cache.data).join(', ')}]</div>
      <div>Current value of '{key}': {cache.get(key) || 'undefined'}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: are you sure you are not using any performance optimization like `memo` or `useCallback` somewhere? different functions are created during each render, if you try to "optimize" any code by assuming there is just 1 `get` or `set` function for all future renders, it will access the old function where `cacheData = {}`

Comment: Nope, I am sure I am not using it! I first tried the clean way, after that I wanted to try to optimize. You responded to my other question as well right? You pointed me in the right direction but still not 100% clear

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question works fine when used as follows. Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem by including following code snippet in your question and editing it until you reproduce the problem:

```js
const {useState, useContext, createContext} = React

const fn = () => undefined
const CacheContext = createContext({data: {}, get: fn, set: fn})

const App = () => {
  const [cacheData, setCacheData] = useState({});
  const getCache = (key) => {
    console.log('Getting value from cache with key ' + key, cacheData);
    return cacheData[key];
  }
  const setCache = (key, data) => {
    try{
      console.log(cacheData);

      console.log('Setting value to cache with key ' + key, data);
      let dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cacheData));
      dataCopy[key] = data;
      console.log(dataCopy, cacheData);
      setCacheData(dataCopy); 
      console.log('jaja');
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <CacheContext.Provider value={{data: cacheData, get: getCache, set: setCache}}>
      <Main />
    </CacheContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Main = () => {
  const {data, get, set} = useContext(CacheContext)
  const [key, setKey] = useState('key')
  const [value, setValue] = useState('value')
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={key} onChange={(e) => setKey(e.target.value)} />
      :
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => set(key, value)}>Set</button>
      <div>Existing keys: [{Object.keys(data).join(', ')}]</div>
      <div>Current value of '{key}': {get(key) || 'undefined'}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

That being said, [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) can be used when `the new state is computed using the previous state`. And if you discover you need a mutable reference for imperative code, async operations, working with closures and/or code optimized for performance, [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) can be used for accessing future values of `data`:

```js
const {useState, useContext, useRef, createContext, memo} = React

const fn = () => undefined
const CacheContext = createContext({data: {}, get: fn, set: fn})

const App = memo(() => {
  const [cacheData, setCacheData] = useState({});
  const dataRef = useRef();
  dataRef.current = cacheData;
  const getCache = (key) => {
    console.log('Getting value from cache with key ' + key, cacheData);
    return cacheData[key];
  }
  const setCache = (key, data) => {
    try{
      console.log(cacheData);

      console.log('Setting value to cache with key ' + key, data);
      setCacheData(current => {
        const dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(current));
        dataCopy[key] = data;
        return dataCopy;
      })
      setCacheData(dataCopy); 
      console.log('jaja');
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <CacheContext.Provider value={{dataRef, get: getCache, set: setCache}}>
      <Main />
    </CacheContext.Provider>
  )
})

const Main = memo(() => {
  const {dataRef, get, set} = useContext(CacheContext)
  const [key, setKey] = useState('key')
  const [value, setValue] = useState('value')
  
  const setAsync = () => {
    set('in progress', key)
    setTimeout(() => {
      set(key, value)
      // notice how mutating a reference will NOT trigger a re-render, unlike using `set`
      // set('in progress', undefined)
      delete dataRef.current['in progress']
    }, 3000)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={key} onChange={(e) => setKey(e.target.value)} />
      :
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={setAsync}>Set</button>
      <div>Existing keys: [{Object.keys(dataRef.current).join(', ')}]</div>
      <div>Current value of '{key}': {get(key) || 'undefined'}</div>
      <div>Current value of 'in progress': {get('in progress') || 'undefined'}</div>
    </div>
  )
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you using LocalStorage or SessionStorage(tab specific)?  Simply push and take from localStorage and you'll be fine man.  Either that or use redux-store along with redux-persist to handle refreshes.

redux: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux

redux-persist: plugin that stores redux-store data to localStorage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: The advantage of context over localStorage is (for me) that it isnt persisted after a page refresh. Redux is too complicated in my opinion for this simple usecase. I might use localstorage if this question isnt answered. Any idea what my solution can be?

Comment: Context is a global react object that is passed from the root to whatever component.  You can use that instead. I'll look into it in a bit and post some working context code

Comment: I am using context already for my auth data, but now I wanted this simple cache (get/set) mechanism. My guess is that the difference here is that I pass functions, although that shouldnt be the problem. Thanks in advance.