# React how to use state in passed function

Tags: reactjs

I am using React context to pass down state. When my state changes, it also changes in the child Component (console logs shows new value), but when this state is used in a function, it doesnt update there (console.log shows old value).

Do I need to rerender the function? How?

```
  const {user, userInfo, ref} = useSession(); <-- wrapper for useContext
  console.log(userInfo); <--- correct, updated value

  const haalDataOp = async () => {
    console.log(userInfo.enelogic); <--- old value displaying
    ...
  }
```

I am using the function haalDataOp from a button (onClick)

As someone already mentioned, I could use useRef, but I dont understand why. Why does this simple example work (extracted from https://dev.to/anpos231/react-hooks-the-closure-hell-71m), and my code doesnt:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    () => {
      setValue(value + 1)
    },
    [value],
  );
```

I also tried using useCallback (with userInfo in the dep array) in my example but that doesnt do the trick.

Comment: where/how are you using `haalDataOp`?

Comment: From a button, added to article

Answer (score 1):

`const ... userInfo ...` is a constant, so in a Component like following:

```
console.log('render', userInfo.enelogic) // different value in each render
const haalDataOp = async () => {
  console.log('before', userInfo.enelogic) // correct old value
  await update()
  console.log('after', userInfo.enelogic)  // still the same old value
}

return <button onClick={haalDataOp} />
```

...it would log:

```
render old
before old
after old
render new
```

...because the `userInfo` inside `haalDataOp` is a closure referencing to the value from the original render. If you need to access a mutable reference that would point to the up-to-date value from a future render instead, you can [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables):

```
const userInfoRef = useRef()
userInfoRef.current = userInfo

console.log('render', userInfo.enelogic) // different value in each render
const haalDataOp = async () => {
  console.log('before', userInfoRef.current.enelogic) // old value
  await update()
  console.log('after', userInfoRef.current.enelogic)  // should be new value
}

return <button onClick={haalDataOp} />
```

However, there might be a race condition and/or the execution of the `'after'` code happens deterministically BEFORE the next render, in which case you will need to use some other trick...

I suspect that the `const {ref} = useSession()` is needed for exactly this situation, so please read the documentation.

Comment: Hi, Im am trying to read your answer but it isnt crystal clear for me. I am not updating my state in this haalDataOp function, I am just doing something WITH that state. The state was updated by some other process (in this case Firebase updates my state) and I was expecting to use the new state in my child component. (the ref mentioned in the useSession hook is the firestore ref, not a react ref)

Comment: It did work using useRef, but I still dont get how this works. Is my other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569798/react-pass-cache-and-get-set-function-in-context also this problem?